# how to navigate user from my facebook application's canvas page to my web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook

I am working on a rails application. I have implemented facebook integration in my application. User can invite his friends to my application. Invitation system is working fine but problem is when any friend of user clicks on request it gets redirected to my facebook applications canvas page. I want that the user be redirected to my web applications landing page instead of in the application's canvas page. I tried to do so by including javascript in page which opens in canvas on facebook.

```
<script>
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
</script>
```

But it is giving me error as following.

```
 Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.
```

How to redirect user to my applications landing page as soon as it land son my canvas page? I want to achieve something similar to pinterest does.
Any help is highly appreciated.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your frame doesn't have access to the `window` object, as that'd let you access Facebook's pages and do nasty stuff to them. You need to do `top.location.href` instead of `window.location.href`.

Answer (score 0):

Your facebook application is probably sending the X-Frame headers, preventing Facebook to include your application iside the iFrame in the first place.

Some applications include that to prevent clickjacking, see here for an explanation of how it works:
http://blog.mozilla.com/security/2010/09/08/x-frame-options/

You might want to disable that header and then try again.